# Update Custom Cell UIButton title when NSNotification is posted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift2

I have a `UITableViewController` with a bunch of custom cells that have a `playButton` in them. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I assign a tag that is is equal to the `indexPath` of the button, so that when the `playButton` is pressed, I set the title of the button to "Stop". It changes to "Stop", as it should, and when I press "Stop", it changes back to "Play".

Where I'm having difficulty is when my sound stops playing on its own, absent user intervention. I set up an observer to listen for the MP3 player being done. I added an observer in `viewDidLoad` of `MyTableViewController`:

Here are the variables I use to facilitate changing the title of the `playButton` in my cells:

```
// Variables to facilitate changing playButton title
var indexPathOfPlayButton = Int()
var isPlaying: Bool = false
```

In `viewDidLoad` of `MyTableViewController`, I add this observer:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "resetPlayButton", name: resetPlayButtonNotification, object: nil)
```

Here's my `playMP3` method on `MyTableViewController`:

```
func playMP3(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isPlaying == false {
        isPlaying = true
        // This gets the indexPath of the button that sent the playMP3 request
        let indexPath = sender.tag
        sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        // This sets the indexPath of the playButton that we'll redraw the button when it receives a notification?
        indexPathOfPlayButton = indexPath

        if resultsSearchController.active {
            let soundToPlay = self.filteredSounds[indexPath]
            let soundFilename = soundToPlay.soundFilename as String
            mp3Player = MP3Player(fileName: soundFilename)
            mp3Player.play()
        } else {
            let soundToPlay = self.unfilteredSounds[indexPath]
            let soundFilename = soundToPlay.soundFilename as String
            mp3Player = MP3Player(fileName: soundFilename)
            mp3Player.play()
        }
    }

    else if isPlaying == true {
        isPlaying = false
        sender.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        mp3Player.stop()
    }
}
```

In my `MP3Player` class, this is the delegate method I use post a notification that it's done:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if currentTrackIndex == tracks.count - 1 {
        print("end of playlist reached")
        player.stop()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(resetPlayButtonNotification, object: self)
    }

    else if flag == true {
        print("advance to next track")
        nextSong(true)
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is the method on `MyTableViewController` that gets called when a notification is posted:

```
func resetPlayButton() {
    print("resetPlayButtonCalled")
    // TODO: How do I get a hold of the button and change the title from outside playMP3?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved! I was setting the `indexPath` of the sender as an Int. Instead, I declared this class variable:

```
// I removed this--> var indexPathOfPlayButton = Int()
var clickedButton = UIButton() // this gets set in playMP3
```

In `playMP3`, I added statement and took out the one where I set the indexPath variable:

```
    let indexPath = sender.tag // The tag which button was pressed (it's set to its indexPath when it's drawn in cellForRowAtIndexPath)
    // Nuked this--> indexPathOfPlayButton = indexPath
    // and replaced with this
    clickedButton = sender as! UIButton
```

Then, in my `resetPlayButton` method, I grab that variable and change the title back to "Play"

```
func resetPlayButton() {
    print("resetPlayButtonCalled")
    clickedButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code, which is not related to the problem your mentioned above. If I understood your problem is that you don't know how to update button in your observer selector `resetPlayButton()`. The button is in the tableview cell and you have stored the index in `indexPathOfPlayButton`.
You can get the cell like:

```
let cell: YourCellClass = tableView.cellForIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: indexPathOfPlayButton, inSection: 0))
```

And after you get the cell, you can update its output.

Another way is to call `reloadData()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured it out. Instead of setting the indexPath variable in `playMP3`, I added a variable for the button to the class and set that in `playMP3`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was using the main thread to post the notification:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("identifier"), object: true, userInfo: ["text": "Purchased"])
}
```